# Weird Cache Problems Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, ngrok

So I am very confused on how Chrome caches information, my problem is I cannot load in my leaflet map. When I run this code in IIS locally Chrome would cache the old site data and would not update anymore. Then I use ngrok and I clear cache and I have no more map.

At the moment my map is not even loading in locally anymore, I am sure this is very easy and I am missing something please someone explain this to me or point me to a resource to help me. Thanks for any help!

Javascript:

```
    // Create map and get user location
$(document).ready(() => {
    createMap()
});

// Map function
const createMap = async () => {
    "use strict"
    let map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const tileOptions = {
        maxZoom: 5,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }
    let OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = await L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', tileOptions).addTo(map);
}

// Update countries list
const getCountry = $.ajax("libs/php/getCountry.php")

getCountry
    .done(result => {
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            result["data"].forEach(el => {
                $('#countryList').append(new Option(el["name"], el["iso_a2"]));
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

// DOM update
$("#search").click(() => {
    console.log($("#countryList").find(":selected").text());

    // // GET COUNTRY BORDERS
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryBorders.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: $('select').val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {
            // ADD COUNTRY BOUDS
            console.log(result["data"]);
        },

        error: function(err) {console.log(err)}
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="source/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="source/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="source/favicon-16x16.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/styles/style.css">
    <title>Gazetter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <!-- <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <select name="countryList" id="countryList" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" name="search" id="search" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div id="mapid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/libs/javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a random string or number to end of all URLs that would load some data which doesn't refresh.

Something like this:

```
const getCountry = $.ajax("libs/php/getCountry.php?rand=" + Math.random())
```

Comment: The issue is with the map from leaflet not from the ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the html with the ids `countryList` and `search` and maybe then the js will throw errors in the lines `$('#countryList').append(new Option(el["name"], el["iso_a2"]));`, `console.log($("#countryList").find(":selected").text());`, `country: $('select').val()`.

I recommand to test only the clean map without loading data.

Also I never saw  `await L.tileLayer('` I don't know if this is working correct but test it without `await`